# iOS - UIWebView replaced with WKWebView, but for Apple it’s still there

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

I’ve replaced the UIWebView with WKWebView in the ViewController in the Storyboard of my Xcode project, but Apple rejected my app saying that UIWebView is deprecated.
Is there a way to check if the UIWebView is still somewhere in the code? I’m using the latest Xcode version, I also have the GoogleMobileAds framework implemented

Comment: Search webview in project, may be any SDK is using this. Otherwise you can communicate in resolution center. Recently I have seen that Apple will rejected UIWebview apps from nov or dec 2020.

Comment: I’ve searched for UIWebView, but found nothing :(

Comment: There may be a chance any SDK is using WKWebview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try from terminal in your base project folder

`grep -r "UIWebView" .`

(Be careful to "dot" at the end of line)

This will print out all SDK's (including Pods) which are currently using UIWebView.

Comment: UIWebView from this Binary file ./JOi.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/cygnet.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate matches, hot to remove UIWebView from this file

Comment: I do not exactly know why is it there but it sounds like it is a user data. You may delete xcuserdata folder, and Xcode will rebuild it again. But be careful, make a copy of the previous version before you delete